# usdt through solana blockchain failed

Tags: blockchain, solana, tether

Retrieve usdt from my Binance account though wrong chain ( Solana) blocked the assets on Solana and opened an error usdt address on it. The transfer is Identified on solscan. The assets didn't reach my usdt Coinbase wallet of course.

How to use  the transit address found on solscan to return to owner ( myself) on Binance or send to receiver (myself) on coinbase ? Help plse.Thanks.